# Retrieving data from JSON object with similar keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON data that is returned from a AJAX GET request. This request returns different sets of meals and how to make them including the ingredients needed and their measurements. Snippet of JSON data (Some key : value have been removed for easier viewing):

```
{
  "idMeal":"52768",
  "strMeal":"Apple Frangipan Tart",
  "strDrinkAlternate":null,
  "strCategory":"Dessert",
  "strIngredient1":"digestive biscuits",
  "strIngredient2":"butter",
  "strIngredient3":"Bramley apples",
  "strIngredient4":"butter, softened",
  "strIngredient5":"caster sugar",
  "strIngredient6":"free-range eggs, beaten",
  "strIngredient7":"ground almonds",
  "strIngredient8":"almond extract",
  "strIngredient9":"flaked almonds",
  "strIngredient10":"",
  "strIngredient11":"",
  "strIngredient12":"",
  "strIngredient13":"",
  "strIngredient14":"",
  "strIngredient15":"",
  "strIngredient16":null,
  "strIngredient17":null,
  "strIngredient18":null,
  "strIngredient19":null,
  "strIngredient20":null,
  "strMeasure1":"175g\/6oz",
  "strMeasure2":"75g\/3oz",
  "strMeasure3":"200g\/7oz",
  "strMeasure4":"75g\/3oz",
  "strMeasure5":"75g\/3oz",
  "strMeasure6":"2",
  "strMeasure7":"75g\/3oz",
  "strMeasure8":"1 tsp",
  "strMeasure9":"50g\/1\u00beoz",
  "strMeasure10":"",
  "strMeasure11":"",
  "strMeasure12":"",
  "strMeasure13":"",
  "strMeasure14":"",
  "strMeasure15":"",
  "strMeasure16":null,
  "strMeasure17":null,
  "strMeasure18":null,
  "strMeasure19":null,
  "strMeasure20":null
},
{
  "idMeal":"52893",
  "strMeal":"Apple & Blackberry Crumble",
  "strDrinkAlternate":null,
  "strCategory":"Dessert",
  "strIngredient1":"Plain Flour",
  "strIngredient2":"Caster Sugar",
  "strIngredient3":"Butter",
  "strIngredient4":"Braeburn Apples",
  "strIngredient5":"Butter",
  "strIngredient6":"Demerara Sugar",
  "strIngredient7":"Blackberrys",
  "strIngredient8":"Cinnamon",
  "strIngredient9":"Ice Cream",
  "strIngredient10":"",
  "strIngredient11":"",
  "strIngredient12":"",
  "strIngredient13":"",
  "strIngredient14":"",
  "strIngredient15":"",
  "strIngredient16":"",
  "strIngredient17":"",
  "strIngredient18":"",
  "strIngredient19":"",
  "strIngredient20":"",
  "strMeasure1":"120g",
  "strMeasure2":"60g",
  "strMeasure3":"60g",
  "strMeasure4":"300g",
  "strMeasure5":"30g",
  "strMeasure6":"30g",
  "strMeasure7":"120g",
  "strMeasure8":"\u00bc teaspoon",
  "strMeasure9":"to serve",
  "strMeasure10":"",
  "strMeasure11":"",
  "strMeasure12":"",
  "strMeasure13":"",
  "strMeasure14":"",
  "strMeasure15":"",
  "strMeasure16":"",
  "strMeasure17":"",
  "strMeasure18":"",
  "strMeasure19":"",
  "strMeasure20":""
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY CODE**

```
$.each($(response), function(key, val) {
      let mealName = val.strMeal;
      let mealCategory = val.strCategory;
      let mealInstructions = val.strInstructions;
      let mealIngredient1 = val.strIngredient1;
      let mealIngredient2 = val.strIngredient2;
      ... // Variables continued
      ...
      let mealIngredient20 = val.strIngredient20;

      let mealMeasure1 = val.strMeasure1;
      let mealMeasure2 = val.strMeasure2;
      ... // Variables continued
      ...
      let mealMeasure20 = val.strMeasure20;

      console.log(mealName);
      console.log(mealCategory);
      console.log(mealInstructions);
      console.log(mealIngredient1);
      console.log(mealIngredient2);
      console.log(mealMeasure1);
      console.log(mealMeasure2);
    });
```

As you can see, each meal can have up to 20 ingredients and measurements and will differ from one another. So, my question is whether there is a better or more efficient way in getting each ingredient and measurement than my method of retrieving each and storing in an individual variable, while also getting rid of null or empty variables that won't be used?

Comment: efficient way compared to what ?

Comment: In the JavaScript code snippet, at the moment I get each ingredient and measurement individually and store in a variable, but I find this way makes my code look repetitive and some variables might not be used depending on the number of ingredients there are for each meal

Comment: In that case instead of repeated assignments build an array out of it

Comment: But how would I go about checking if the strIngredients1-20 keys contain a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Description) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = {
  "idMeal":"52768",
  "strMeal":"Apple Frangipan Tart",
  "strDrinkAlternate":null,
  "strCategory":"Dessert",
  "strIngredient1":"digestive biscuits",
  "strIngredient2":"butter",
  "strIngredient3":"Bramley apples",
  "strIngredient4":"butter, softened",
  "strIngredient5":"caster sugar",
  "strIngredient6":"free-range eggs, beaten",
  "strIngredient7":"ground almonds",
  "strIngredient8":"almond extract",
  "strIngredient9":"flaked almonds",
  "strIngredient10":"",
  "strIngredient11":"",
  "strIngredient12":"",
  "strIngredient13":"",
 }
 

// get an array of [key, value] entries from the response
const properties = Object.entries(data);

// filter out the items whose value is empty
const nonEmpty = properties.filter(([_, value]) => value);

// do whatever you need to do with the rest
nonEmpty.map(([name, value]) => console.log(`${name}: ${value}`));
```

The code above can be tightened up by chaining the filter and map operations:

```js
Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([_, value]) => value )
  .map(([key, value]) => console.log( key, value ));
```

You can also extract and/or filter non-ingredient properties separately if that's useful:

```js
const data = {
  "idMeal": "52768",
  "strMeal": "Apple Frangipan Tart",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Dessert",
  "strIngredient1": "digestive biscuits",
  "strIngredient2": "butter",
  "strIngredient3": "Bramley apples",
  "strIngredient4": "butter, softened",
  "strIngredient5": "caster sugar",
  "strIngredient6": "free-range eggs, beaten",
  "strIngredient7": "ground almonds",
  "strIngredient8": "almond extract",
  "strIngredient9": "flaked almonds",
  "strIngredient10": "",
  "strIngredient11": "",
  "strIngredient12": "",
  "strIngredient13": "",
}

// extract a few known properties, and capture the rest in the 'others' variable.
const {idMeal, strMeal, ...others} = data;

Object.entries(others)
  .filter(([_, value]) => value) // no empty values
  .filter(([key]) => key.includes('Ingredient')) // only 'ingredient' items
  .map(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added this code and it has reduced the number of lines but I wish to use the ingredients and their measurements to add to my website and I also find this way does not get rid of the null or empty values that may be in the JSON object (meal).

Comment: Updated the sample code to filter out the empty items.

Comment: I did not see your edited solution before posting my previous comment. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks in advance

Comment: Added another snippet showing how to filter out non-ingredient keys.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I have been trying to understand and use the following solution snippets in my code. However, it seems as if the first filter does not get rid of the strIngredient keys that have an empty or null value. When logging the nonEmpty variable to the console, it returns the same array as the response (or data variable from your code snippet)

Comment: Are you seeing different behavior in your project than what you see when you run the snippets above? The filtering is working for me here, but it's possible there's a data or browser difference. You can tweak the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do whatever you need it to do. Also keep in mind that `filter` does not alter the array. It returns a *new* array with only those items that pass the filter.

Comment: Your solution was correct. I had forgotten to step through the JSON data one more time to get the desired result but I got there in the end. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your strIngredient# object properties should be an array strIngredient[] which you can iterate over dynamicly, likewise with strMeasure[]. As your code is written now you are setting a lot of properties that are uneccessary depending on the given recepie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destructuring and use rest operator to get the remaining parts.

```js
const data = {
   "idMeal":"52768",
   "strMeal":"Apple Frangipan Tart",
   "strDrinkAlternate":null,
   "strCategory":"Dessert",
   "strIngredient1":"digestive biscuits",
   "strIngredient2":"butter",
   "strIngredient3":"Bramley apples",
   "strIngredient4":"butter, softened",
   "strIngredient5":"caster sugar",
   "strIngredient6":"free-range eggs, beaten",
   "strIngredient7":"ground almonds",
   "strIngredient8":"almond extract",
   "strIngredient9":"flaked almonds",
   "strIngredient10":"",
   "strIngredient11":"",
   "strIngredient12":"",
   "strIngredient13":"",
   "strIngredient14":"",
   "strIngredient15":"",
   "strIngredient16":null,
   "strIngredient17":null,
   "strIngredient18":null,
   "strIngredient19":null,
   "strIngredient20":null,
   "strMeasure1":"175g\/6oz",
   "strMeasure2":"75g\/3oz",
   "strMeasure3":"200g\/7oz",
   "strMeasure4":"75g\/3oz",
   "strMeasure5":"75g\/3oz",
   "strMeasure6":"2",
   "strMeasure7":"75g\/3oz",
   "strMeasure8":"1 tsp",
   "strMeasure9":"50g\/1\u00beoz",
   "strMeasure10":"",
   "strMeasure11":"",
   "strMeasure12":"",
   "strMeasure13":"",
   "strMeasure14":"",
   "strMeasure15":"",
   "strMeasure16":null,
   "strMeasure17":null,
   "strMeasure18":null,
   "strMeasure19":null,
   "strMeasure20":null
};

const { idMeal,  strMeal, strDrinkAlternate, strCategory, ...rest } = data;
console.log(rest);
```